# How to check a String in a set (Find_IN_SET) using MongoDB Java

Tags: mongodb-java

I am working on a web-services code in MongoDB using Java ,I have a table where one of the column contains range values like 1,2,3 or 3,4,5 or 6,7,8 . Given a value like 2 , I have to check whether the value lies in each of the specified ranges 
I tried the following query in MYSQL

> select * from Table where FIND_IN_SET('2',RangeField)

and the java code i have tried is

```
BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
whereQuery.put("RangeField","2");
DBCursor cursor = col.find(whereQuery);
```

I don't have any idea about the right syntax  to define find_in_set in Mongo Java.
RangeField is String in table and its like 1,2,3 or 3f,5f. How to replicate the same in mondoDB java code

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regex` to get all the records which contains search string.

In MongoDB :

```
db.Table.find({"RangeField":{$regex:"2"}}); //List records which contain 2 anywhere
```

In Java :

```
BasicDBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
dbObject.put("RangeField",  java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("2"));
try(DBCursor cursor = collection.find(dbObject))
{
    while (cursor.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println((BasicDBObject) cursor.next());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How to check a String in a set (Find_IN_SET) using Mongoose

"$in" is an operator in MongoDB that is used to check if a value is in a set of values. The "$in" operator is often used in the "$match" stage of an aggregation pipeline to filter documents based on the values of a specific field.

```
/* Javascript */ 

Model.aggregate([
   {
      $match: {
         field: { $in: [ "value1", "value2", "value3" ] }
      }
   }
])
   .exec()
   .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
   });
```

https://www.cltechhome.com/2023/02/how-to-check-string-in-set-findinset.html